# Which full backup will be differential one based on?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, backup, windows-server

I wanted to perform a differential backup of a DB in SQL Server 2008.
I currently have a *.bak* file with a full backup and I want to add this new one in it.

Will be the differential backup based on the existing one contained in the *.bak* file? Or will it be based on another full backup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will be based off your most recent full backup, a differential backup is simply a backup of changed pages since your last full backup. Hope that helps.

Comment: What do I have to do if my existing full backup is not the latest one?

Comment: what backups do you have currently? How many full? when was the latest full taken?

Comment: Currently I have just one full backup that was taken the 2nd of october.

Comment: This is simple recovery model I presume, if the last backup is definitely the full on 2nd October then differential would suffice. I hope this isn't a prod database;) The below script will get the last backup date just to confirm.

Comment: select a.name [Database Name], max(b.backup_finish_date)[Last Backup Finish Date] from sys.databases a left join msdb.dbo.backupset b on b.database_name = a.name group by a.name

Comment: Actually it is a prod DB... Fortunatelly this isn't a recovery but just a migration.

Comment: I've checked, i have the last full backup as listed in the result of the query you gave me.

Thanks for your help!